# context.User is empty. Why?

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm exposing an API using Azure API Management and I need to add a header on return... I'm trying to add a context.User.Id information, but I'm always receiving messages that the object is not set.

My policy is below:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="user" exists-action="override">
            <value>@(context.User.Id)</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I'm trying to set the user login (id) as a header, but when I run the api I'm receiving the following error:

```
set-header (0.724 ms)
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "message": "Expression evaluation failed.",
            "expression": "context.User.Id",
            "details": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        },
        "Expression evaluation failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    ]
}
```

This api is protect using Oauth2 and I'm passing the right access-token. How I can I get the user information to use it on header?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The usage of oauth token doesn't mean the context will be filled. To extract the user information that I needed I had to decode the content of the JWT token and the the user login from there with the following code:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="Login" exists-action="override">
            <value>@{
                string login = "";
                string authHeader = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "");
                if (authHeader.Length > 0) {
                    string[] authHeaderParts = authHeader.Split(' ');
                    if (authHeaderParts.Length == 2 && authHeaderParts[0].Equals("Bearer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                        Jwt jwt;
                        if (authHeaderParts[1].TryParseJwt(out jwt)) {
                            login = jwt.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("unique_name", "").Split('@')[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
                return login;
            }</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 0):

The context.User seems to provide data from the subscription owner.

For this field to have any values, the end-user must provide a subscription key associated with a user.

This is not available for the consumption SKU.